# How to resolve "unfortunately <myapp> has stopped"

Tags: android

Just for your info, I'm new to android development and I'm trying to learn by creating a simple app. However, I have come across a problem which I cannot resolve and would also add, I can't find a solution in either stackoverflow or google.

Basically, when I try to compile and launch my android app on android emulator, I get "unfortunately myapp has stopped" message. Looking at my code, I have noticed that I get this message when I try to add an event listener to a component (in my case it is a seekbar). I'm neither getting any compile error nor am I getting any thing on my logcat. Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Any help is much appricated. I have posted my event listener code below

```
private OnSeekBarChangeListener customSeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            // update currentCustomPercent, then call updateCustom
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                  boolean fromUser)
    {
        // sets currentCustomPercent to position of the SeekBar's thumb
        currentCustomPercent = seekBar.getProgress();
        updateCustom(); // update EditTexts for custom tip and total
    } // end method onProgressChanged

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
    {
    } // end method onStartTrackingTouch

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
    {
    } // end method onStopTrackingTouch
}; // end OnSeekBarChangeListener
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it goes to the "unfortunately ... has stopped" state, there ought to be exception stacktrace in logcat. Just check that you don't have any logcat filters on that would prevent it from displaying. Also, check the code where you obtain a reference to your seekbar and set the listener. Reading between your lines possibly the reference is null.

Answer (score 0):

This message essentially means your app crashed/threw an unhandled exception.

The easiest way to solve this without digging too deep into debugging tools etc. is looking at the logcat output.

Open a commmand prompt/terminal window and run `adb logcat`.

This will print lots of lines with different status messages. Wait a few seconds for it to slow down (depends on how fast your console prints etc, e.g. on Windows it might take a bit longer).

Then run your program. Once it "stopped", you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the console window and scroll up to see the error message followed by a stack trace.

Note that you'll have to have USB debugging enabled in the developer settings.

If you're using an IDE, e.g. Android Studio or Eclipse, you should look for the logcat window as it will print that information for you, usually formatted in some more readable way as well.